# I'm not well enough or I'm not good enough

Tags: difference

I'm sick so I can't go to university yet, so should I say:

1-I'm not well enough to go to university

2-I'm not good enough to go to university

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When talking about health, we use *well*, but we don't usually use *good*.

*I'm not good enough* in any context is talking about my ability, my competence, or my virtue, not about my health.